# How to Query Sales Order by Order Number?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I've gotten frustrated with the .NET DevKit and am now considering switching my app over to XML. But I'm still having trouble figuring out how to perform very basic queries.

How can I retrieve a QBD Sales Order by the order number? This is the "Sales Order Number" in the QBD UI, "RefNumber" in the SDK, and "DocNumber" in IPP.

Just in case somebody needs me to explain the use case for looking up a record by the human-readable unique ID: I'm integrating with a system where we don't have the luxury of storing a QB transaction ID after importing a sales order. So if that system wants to query QB later to check the status of a sales order, it needs to do so by that system's unique order #.

I already have links to all the documentation; thanks. I just need to know how to perform this query. Similarly, I need to do it for Invoices and POs.

I need the same thing for Items, the use case being that if we're importing items from another system, we need to query the QB item list by name to see if we already have that item in QB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ITEMS, you can use ItemConsolidated and a NameContains filter. For example, the XML would look something like:

```
POST https://services.intuit.com/sb/itemconsolidated/v2/<realmID>
...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ItemConsolidatedQuery xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2     RestDataFilter.xsd ">
    <NameContains>Your item name goes here</NameContains>
</ItemConsolidatedQuery>
```

It won't be perfect, because Intuit only supports "NameContains" (the item name contains the string you specify) rather than "NameEquals", but you can then loop through what you get back and filter it client-side from there.

For SALES ORDERS, unfortunately, Intuit Data Services doesn't support querying by DocNumber at this time.

Instead, a work-around for your situation might be to query for *all* sales orders, and then cache the Id and DocNumber value of each in your application. When you need to look something up, look up the Id in the cache, and then query by Id value. It's not pretty... but it's really the only way you can do what you're describing.

Comment: Thanks. I totally overlooked ItemConsolidated. That will help.

Comment: Was hoping to avoid caching or any kind of data store re: sales orders, but I think you're right. For various reasons it's a bit awkward in my situation but I think that's what we'll have to do.